# Reset Dropzone after file are uploaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I am using `dropzone.js` to uploads images to my php server. I have used jquery ajax call to save the form after all images are uploaded.

Now, i want to clear the dropzone div when form values are saved on the server. I have tried **removeAllFiles()** , but it removes files from server too.

I have googled so many times but not getting any right idea. Please provide any help if anyone knows .
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Could you please provide HTML and JS code?

Comment: sorry @heroin but just because of security reasons, i can't do that....

Comment: Ok, then one possible solution is just to hide those tag elements corresponding to files, which were already loaded to the server. Just use ``display: none;`` for them. Is it ok?

Comment: Actually, by default it should not delete files on a server.
Look at the code:

    ``addRemoveLinks: true,
    removedfile: function(file) {
    var _ref;
    return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
    }``

Comment: thanks for your response, I have done my job by using a flag variable and checking the flag variable while using deleteAllFiles by not making a call to server...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add event handler to "queuecomplete" of the dropzone. In this handler, do whatever you want. In the example, I reload all uploaded files, and removeAllFiles().

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  init: function(){
      var th = this;
      this.on('queuecomplete', function(){
          ImageUpload.loadImage();  // CALL IMAGE LOADING HERE
          setTimeout(function(){
              th.removeAllFiles();
          },5000);
      })
  },
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB       
  acceptedFiles: 'image/*',

};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my.on("complete", function(file) { my.removeFile(file); });
my.on("complete", function(file) { my.removeAllFiles(file);});
```

Comment: Add some brief explanation of what your code is doing.